# Meteor 0.9 Local Package Location

Tags: javascript, meteor

I noticed that somehow there is no packages folder in my newly created Meteor 0.9 project. This means that it must be using package from the `~/.meteor` things. However, I cannot work like this as I am hopping between machines all day and I would like the package to stay locally; like in the project folder itself.

In the previous Meteor 0.8.3 project, I manually  created packages folder in the project and when I add package it went inside there (for example i can find collectionFs inside package/ in the project directory).

I want it to be like this. How can I do this safely?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can still drop packages into the top-level "packages" directory inside your project and then run `meteor add` like usual. These packages are just treated as app-specific packages. Here are [the docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#usingpackages) about using packages. The relevant bit is quoted here:

> In addition to the packages in the official Meteor release being used by your app, meteor list and meteor add also search the packages directory at the top of your app.

Answer (score 1):

I think the idea was to delineate the stand-alone application code from 3rd party libraries. As a package author, this means there are less forks of my library with subtle changes floating around on Atmosphere. It also makes your apps a bit less prone to bugs (given the packages are stable), and encourages better package maintenance.

If you want to use local packages though, here is a good [walk-through](http://www.webtempest.com/meteor-js-packages-tutorial).

For NPM packages, also check out `meteorhacks:npm` | [github](https://github.com/meteorhacks/npm)

Answer (score 0):

For the collectionFS, you have to use meteor 0.6 version.
You have to add new release file of meteor 0.6 version.
https://github.com/CollectionFS/Meteor-cfs-example-filemanager